# Short preferences activity (two options) not retaining values if app is removed from memory.

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, preferences

Here's my attempt at a preferences settings activity. It's hacked, but has no deprecated methods. It grew out of a hack that did NOT use preferences. That hack **works** *until the app leaves the list of apps currently in memory,* at which point the values are reset as if it were `firstUse` upon next use.

Adding the preferences code (in `dealWithPreferences` and `onOptionsItemSelected`) changed nothing about that. Works fine as long as app remains in memory. Once it leaves, we're back to `firstUse`.

The added code came from modifying a textbook example, which is definitely not a "modern" way of dealing with preferences. Very short. It's from Sams Teach Yourself Android App Development in 24 hours. I guess I'm not up to the challenge. Or maybe the code in the text is buggy. Or both.

I just want to save persistently two preferences. So far, no go.

Here's the 94-line SSCCE with xml to follow. I really hacked off a ton of code, leaving only the barest of bones to see the problem. (BTW, I also tried `extends PreferenceActivity`; no change.)

```
    package com.whatever.Prefer;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
    import android.view.Window;
    import java.lang.reflect.Field;

    public class MyActivity extends Activity{
      boolean debugging = false, firstUse, screenSaver, focusAtClue;
      public final String
          prefix = "com.whatever.prefer",
          SETTINGS = prefix + ".settings",
          FIRST_USE = prefix + ".firstUse",
          FOCUS_AT_CLUE = prefix + ".focusAtClue",
          SCREENSAVER = prefix + ".screensaver",
          literally_Focus_At_Clue = "Focus at clue",
          literally_Screen_saver = "Screen saver";
      SharedPreferences preferences;
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

      private void dealWithPreferences(){
        preferences = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        boolean firstUse = preferences.getBoolean(FIRST_USE, true);
        if (firstUse) {
          editor.putBoolean(FIRST_USE, false);
          focusAtClue = true;
          screenSaver = true;
          editor.putBoolean(FOCUS_AT_CLUE, focusAtClue);
          editor.putBoolean(SCREENSAVER, screenSaver);
        }
        else {
          editor.putBoolean(FIRST_USE, false);
          editor.putBoolean(FOCUS_AT_CLUE, focusAtClue);
          editor.putBoolean(SCREENSAVER, screenSaver);
        }
        editor.commit();
      }

      @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        dealWithPreferences();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFormat(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        makeActionOverflowMenuShown();
      } // onCreate

      private void makeActionOverflowMenuShown(){ // a hack from SO
        try {
          ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
          Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
          if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
      }

      @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
      }

      @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        preferences = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Toggle whichever item was tapped
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.itemScreensaver:
            if (item.getTitle().toString().equals(literally_Screen_saver)) {
              item.setTitle("No " + literally_Screen_saver);
              screenSaver = false;
            }
            else {
              item.setTitle(literally_Screen_saver);
              screenSaver = true;
            }
            break;
          case R.id.itemFocus:
            if (item.getTitle().toString().equals(literally_Focus_At_Clue)) {
              item.setTitle("No " + literally_Focus_At_Clue);
              focusAtClue = false;
            }
            else {
              item.setTitle(literally_Focus_At_Clue);
              focusAtClue = true;
            }
        } // switch
        dealWithPreferences();
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Here's `menu_my.xml`.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/itemHelp"
          android:title="Tap below to toggle option..."
          android:orderInCategory="10"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/itemFocus"
          android:title="@string/focusAtClue"
          android:orderInCategory="200"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/itemScreensaver"
          android:title="@string/screenSaver"
          android:orderInCategory="300"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

And `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"
 ?>
    <manifest
        xmlns:android=  "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package=        "com.whatever.Prefer"
        >

        <application
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            >

            <activity
                android:screenOrientation=  "portrait"
                android:label=              "BS"
                android:icon=               "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:name=               ".MyActivity"
                >

                <intent-filter>

                    <action
                        android:name=   "android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    />

                    <category
                        android:name=   "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                    />

                </intent-filter>

            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

What is supposed to happen is this. When the user taps the action bar overflow settings icon, the menu below pops up and the user can toggle either "option", which will either add "No" to the text of the option (if absent) or take away "No" (if present).

It works but it doesn't persist.

I realize that this is very hacked, but it's all I need. Surely there's an easy fix (I hope).

What should I do to fix it?

[image]